# Consulta 1-n con Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, jerarquía, relación-1-n

Tengo una tabla llamada `categories` con la siguiente estructura:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->string('icon')->default('no_icon.jpg');
    $table->string('image')->default('no_image.jpg');
    $table->text('description')->nullable();
    $table->bigInteger('parent_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

La idea es que el campo `parent_id` se relacione con el campo `id` de la misma tabla, de forma que unas categorías puedan depender jerárquicamente de otras. Para ello, además, he creado la siguiente migration:

```
Schema::table('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    //** CLAVE FORÁNEA */
    $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
});
```

En el modelo de la tabla, llamado `Category`, tengo los siguientes métodos:

```
public function parentCategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
}

public function childrenCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

La idea es que, dado un objeto de la clase, el método `parentCategory()` me devuelva un objeto con la clase padre (aquella a la que apunta la propiedad `parent_id` del primer objeto).

Así mismo, dado un objeto de la clase, el método `childrenCategories()` debería darme las categorías que dependen de dicho objeto, es decir, aquellas que, en su propiedad `parent_id` tienen el mismo valor que la propiedad `id` del primer objeto.

Vamos, es una relación jerárquica `1-n` de manual. Sin embargo, no me funciona. Con Tinker creo un objeto de la clase sobre el registro con `id = 8`, de la tabla. Este tiene, en `parent_id`, el valor `2`, indicando que depende del registro `2` de dicha tabla. El objeto lo materializo así:

```
$cat8 = App\Category::find(8)
```

Para obtener la categoría padre de este objeto hago lo siguiente:

```
$padre_de_8 = $cat8->parentCategory()->get()
```

En la tabla, esta categoría depende de la `2` (tiene el valor `2` en `parent_id`). Por lo tanto, debería obtener un objeto que represente a la fila `2` de la tabla. Sin embargo, obtengo una colección con todos los elementos, así:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3336
   all: [],
}
```

Para obtener los hijos también me falla. En la tabla hay tres categorías que dependen de la `2` (tienen el valor `2` en `parent_id`). Primero obtengo la categoría `2`, así:

```
$cat2 = App\Models\Category::find(2)
```

Esto me da un objeto con la categoría `2` de la tabla. Ahora ejecuto lo siguiente:

```
$childrenOf2 = $cat2->childrenCategories()->get()
```

Sin embargo, el resultado tampoco es el correcto.

El modelo `Category` completo es el siguiente:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Tag;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Category extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'categories';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'icon',
        'image',
        'description',
        'parent_id',
    ];

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }

    public function parentCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function childrenCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Creo haberlo hecho correctamente, según lo que indica la documentación, pero está claro que algo se me ha pasado por alto. Ah, estoy usando Laravel 7.

Comment: La verdad no entendí lo que quieres hacer... La pregunta me pareció confusa.

Comment: No necesita dos tablas porque está buscando relacionar elementos en la misma tabla.

Comment: Me parece que tu error esta en tratar de hacer `get`. ¿`$cat8->parentCategory()->get()` puedes intentar hacer eso pero sin el get? El get no es necesario cuando usas las relaciones de Eloquent, y de ser necesario vendría en al documentación de Laravel.

Comment: Lo que estas haciendo esta mal, no puedes hacer una relacion 1:n en la "misma tabla". Si tu objetivo es que "dependan unas de otras", entonces se crea otra tabla para donde se guardara esa informacion. O simplemente no relaciones y utiliza el campo "parent_id" para agrupar los que quieres

Comment: @JuanRivera no está mal. El busca relacionar una categoría padre con una categoría hija. Es una relación jerárquica de los elementos de una misma tabla. Lo que estaría mal es lo que tú propones. Hacer dos tablas Categoría y SubCategoría. Te pregunto, ¿Qué pasa si las subcategories tienen otras subcategorias? ¿Vas a crear la tabla SubSubCategorias? Eso si estaría mal.

Comment: @Jacobo creo que tampoco es incorrecto manejar dos tablas para las relaciones. Donde una tabla contiene las definiciones de todas las categorías y otra tabla maneja las relaciones. Donde una categoría puede tener incluso más de una subcategoría y a su vez, puede haber otras subcategorías. En lo personal prefiero esta manera.

Comment: @Jacobo mmm viendolo de esa forma esta bien, pero se tendria que preguntar los requerimientos del OP porque se puede manejar con 2(si solo habra subcategoria) o una(si habra n sub subs) como dices

Comment: No es necesario. Ahora imagina una situación de crear relaciones de Abuelo, Padre, Hijo, Nieto. No vas a crear más de n subclases porque todos son a fin de cuentas personas y puedes relacionarlos aunque haya más de un nivel de jerarquía.

Answer (score 1):

Mirando la documentación y experimentando he encontrado la mejor solución (creo que sea la mejor). La pongo, por si a alguien le resulta útil.

En caso de una relación `1-n` (un padre, muchos hijos), los métodos del modelo `Category` deben quedar así:

```
public function parentCategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function childrenCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

En el caso, como han apuntado en algún comentario, de una relación `m-n` (un hijo muchos padres y un padre muchos hijos), hay que crear una tabla pivote que, según los convencionalismos de Laravel, se llamará `categories_categories`, con una migration como la siguiente:

```
Schema::create('categories_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->bigInteger('parent_id')->unsigned();
    $table->bigInteger('child_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
    // CLAVES FORANEAS
    $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    $table->foreign('child_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
});
```

Los métodos del modelo `Category` para las relaciones deben quedar así:

```
public function parentCategories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'categories_categories', 'child_id', 'parent_id');
}

public function childrenCategories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'categories_categories', 'parent_id', 'child_id');
}
```

Y una cosa muy importante, que no te dice ningún manual ni documentación. Cuando se cambia algo en el modelo, y se graba, hay que salir de Tinker y volver a entrar. Si no, Tinker se "aferra" al modelo en su estado anterior, y no coge los cambios. Y no, usar `php artisan cache:clear`, en este contexto no funciona.